# using c++ string class functions to make "gene substrings" from a longer original Genome string

Tags: c++, string, function, class

Please Help

```
//purpose:  find Genes in genome  and cout found genes


#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cctype>
#include <cmath>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int main() 
{

    string genome = "TTATGTTTTAAGGATGGGGCGTTAGTT"; //using this string to test my code 
    //cout << "Enter a genome string: \n";
    //cin >> genome;

    cout <<genome.find("ATG") <<endl;

    while(!genome.empty())  //enters loop if strings not empty
    {
    if(genome.find("ATG",0) == npos) //genome.find("ATG",0,3) should return npos if no ATG is found right? 
    {                                 //Tried this if statment with = and == but no difference  
        genome.clear(); 
    }
    else
    {
        int startGene = genome.find("ATG",0); //ATG is not part of gene just a front endcap to genes
        int endGene = min(min(genome.find("TAG"), genome.find("TAA")), genome.find("TGA"));//endcaps are TAG or TAA or TGA 
                                                                                           //finds location of (1+ gene end) 


        string currentGene = genome.substr(startGene + 3, endGene - (startGene +3)) <<endl; //puts copy of gene in substring

        if((currentGene.length() % 3) == 0);
        {
            cout << currentGene; //a gene is a multiple of three characters so if its a gene I cout the gene
        }

        endGene += 3;
        genome.erase(0, (endGene)); //should erase the gene I just "cout"displayed 
                                                    //and its front ATG and its endcap and anything before its ATG

        cout << genome; //testing: this should display the genome after the endcap of the last gene cause I erased all coming before 
    }
    }



    return 0;
}
```

end of my code
here's a problem with

```
if(genome.find("ATG",0) == npos)
```

it calls npos a undiclared identifyer I think. I thought npos was what find would return if it didn't find ATG

theres a problem with this which I find strange since it worked when I didn't put it into variable currentGene but just used cout for this substring

```
string currentGene = genome.substr(startGene + 3, endGene - (startGene +3)) <<endl;
```

it says

```
010\projects\genome\genome\genome.cpp(34): error C2784: 'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::operator <<(std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &,const std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc> &)' : could not deduce template argument for 'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &' from 'std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax>'
```

another problem

```
if((currentGene.length() % 3) == 0);
        {
            cout << currentGene; //a gene is a multiple of three characters so if its a gene I cout the gene
        }



error report cut a litle of the repeats at the end

1>------ Build started: Project: genome, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>Build started 11/26/2013 11:49:10 PM.
1>InitializeBuildStatus:
1>  Touching "Debug\genome.unsuccessfulbuild".
1>ClCompile:
1>  genome.cpp
1>c:\documents and settings\dell\my documents\visual studio 2010\projects\genome\genome\genome.cpp(34): error C2784: 'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::operator <<(std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &,const std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc> &)' : could not deduce template argument for 'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &' from 'std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax>'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>,
1>              _Ax=std::allocator<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\string(489) : see declaration of 'std::operator <<'
1>c:\documents and settings\dell\my documents\visual studio 2010\projects\genome\genome\genome.cpp(34): error C2784: 'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::operator <<(std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &,const std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc> &)' : could not deduce template argument for 'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &' from 'std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax>'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>,
1>              _Ax=std::allocator<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\string(489) : see declaration of 'std::operator <<'
1>c:\documents and settings\dell\my documents\visual studio 2010\projects\genome\genome\genome.cpp(34): error C2784: 'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::operator <<(std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &,const std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc> &)' : could not deduce template argument for 'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &' from 'std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax>'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>,
1>              _Ax=std::allocator<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\string(489) : see declaration of 'std::operator <<'
1>c:\documents and settings\dell\my documents\visual studio 2010\projects\genome\genome\genome.cpp(34): error C2784: 'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::operator <<(std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &,const std::error_code &)' : could not deduce template argument for 'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &' from 'std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax>'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>,
1>              _Ax=std::allocator<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\ostream(1085) : see declaration of 'std::operator <<'
1>c:\documents and settings\dell\my documents\visual studio 2010\projects\genome\genome\genome.cpp(34): error C2784: 'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::operator <<(std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &,const std::error_code &)' : could not deduce template argument for 'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &' from 'std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax>'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>,
1>              _Ax=std::allocator<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\ostream(1085) : see declaration of 'std::operator <<'
1>c:\documents and settings\dell\my documents\visual studio 2010\projects\genome\genome\genome.cpp(34): error C2784: 'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::operator <<(std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &,const std::error_code &)' : could not deduce template argument for 'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &' from 'std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax>'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>,
1>              _Ax=std::allocator<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\ostream(1085) : see declaration of 'std::operator <<'
1>c:\documents and settings\dell\my documents\visual studio 2010\projects\genome\genome\genome.cpp(34): error C2784: 'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::operator <<(std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &&,_Ty)' : could not deduce template argument for 'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &&' from 'std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax>'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>,
1>              _Ax=std::allocator<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\ostream(968) : see declaration of 'std::operator <<'
1>c:\documents and settings\dell\my documents\visual studio 2010\projects\genome\genome\genome.cpp(34): error C2784: 'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::operator <<(std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &&,_Ty)' : could not deduce template argument for 'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &&' from 'std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax>'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>,
1>              _Ax=std::allocator<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\ostream(968) : see declaration of 'std::operator <<'
1>c:\documents and settings\dell\my documents\visual studio 2010\projects\genome\genome\genome.cpp(34): error C2784: 'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::operator <<(std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &&,_Ty)' : could not deduce template argument for 'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &&' from 'std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax>'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>,
1>              _Ax=std::allocator<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\ostream(968) : see declaration of 'std::operator <<'
1>c:\documents and settings\dell\my documents\visual studio 2010\projects\genome\genome\genome.cpp(34): error C2784: 'std::basic_ostream<char,_Traits> &std::operator <<(std::basic_ostream<char,_Traits> &,unsigned char)' : could not deduce template argument for 'std::basic_ostream<char,_Traits> &' from 'std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax>'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>,
1>              _Ax=std::allocator<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\ostream(958) : see declaration of 'std::operator <<'
1>c:\documents and settings\dell\my documents\visual studio 2010\projects\genome\genome\genome.cpp(34): error C2784: 'std::basic_ostream<char,_Traits> &std::operator <<(std::basic_ostream<char,_Traits> &,unsigned char)' : could not deduce template argument for 'std::basic_ostream<char,_Traits> &' from 'std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax>'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>,
1>              _Ax=std::allocator<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\ostream(958) : see declaration of 'std::operator <<'
1>c:\documents and settings\dell\my documents\visual studio 2010\projects\genome\genome\genome.cpp(34): error C2784: 'std::basic_ostream<char,_Traits> &std::operator <<(std::basic_ostream<char,_Traits> &,unsigned char)' : could not deduce template argument for 'std::basic_ostream<char,_Traits> &' from 'std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax>'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>,
1>              _Ax=std::allocator<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\ostream(958) : see declaration of 'std::operator <<'
1>c:\documents and settings\dell\my documents\visual studio 2010\projects\genome\genome\genome.cpp(34): error C2784: 'std::basic_ostream<char,_Traits> &std::operator <<(std::basic_ostream<char,_Traits> &,const unsigned char *)' : could not deduce template argument for 'std::basic_ostream<char,_Traits> &' from 'std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax>'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>,
1>              _Ax=std::allocator<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\ostream(951) : see declaration of 'std::operator <<'
1>c:\documents and settings\dell\my documents\visual studio 2010\projects\genome\genome\genome.cpp(34): error C2784: 'std::basic_ostream<char,_Traits> &std::operator <<(std::basic_ostream<char,_Traits> &,const unsigned char *)' : could not deduce template argument for 'std::basic_ostream<char,_Traits> &' from 'std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax>'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>,
1>              _Ax=std::allocator<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\ostream(951) : see declaration of 'std::operator <<'
1>c:\documents and settings\dell\my documents\visual studio 2010\projects\genome\genome\genome.cpp(34): error C2784: 'std::basic_ostream<char,_Traits> &std::operator <<(std::basic_ostream<char,_Traits> &,const unsigned char *)' : could not deduce template argument for 'std::basic_ostream<char,_Traits> &' from 'std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax>'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>,
1>              _Ax=std::allocator<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\ostream(951) : see declaration of 'std::operator <<'
1>c:\documents and settings\dell\my documents\visual studio 2010\projects\genome\genome\genome.cpp(34): error C2784: 'std::basic_ostream<char,_Traits> &std::operator <<(std::basic_ostream<char,_Traits> &,signed char)' : could not deduce template argument for 'std::basic_ostream<char,_Traits> &' from 'std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax>'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>,
1>              _Ax=std::allocator<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\ostream(944) : see declaration of 'std::operator <<'
1>c:\documents and settings\dell\my documents\visual studio 2010\projects\genome\genome\genome.cpp(34): error C2784: 'std::basic_ostream<char,_Traits> &std::operator <<(std::basic_ostream<char,_Traits> &,signed char)' : could not deduce template argument for 'std::basic_ostream<char,_Traits> &' from 'std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax>'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>,
1>              _Ax=std::allocator<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\ostream(944) : see declaration of 'std::operator <<'
1>c:\documents and settings\dell\my documents\visual studio 2010\projects\genome\genome\genome.cpp(34): error C2784: 'std::basic_ostream<char,_Traits> &std::operator <<(std::basic_ostream<char,_Traits> &,signed char)' : could not deduce template argument for 'std::basic_ostream<char,_Traits> &' from 'std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax>'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>,
1>              _Ax=std::allocator<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\ostream(944) : see declaration of 'std::operator <<'
1>c:\documents and settings\dell\my documents\visual studio 2010\projects\genome\genome\genome.cpp(34): error C2784: 'std::basic_ostream<char,_Traits> &std::operator <<(std::basic_ostream<char,_Traits> &,const signed char *)' : could not deduce template argument for 'std::basic_ostream<char,_Traits> &' from 'std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax>'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>,
1>              _Ax=std::allocator<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\ostream(937) : see declaration of 'std::operator <<'
1>c:\documents and settings\dell\my documents\visual studio 2010\projects\genome\genome\genome.cpp(34): error C2784: 'std::basic_ostream<char,_Traits> &std::operator <<(std::basic_ostream<char,_Traits> &,const signed char *)' : could not deduce template argument for 'std::basic_ostream<char,_Traits> &' from 'std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax>'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>,
1>              _Ax=std::allocator<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\ostream(937) : see declaration of 'std::operator <<'
1>c:\documents and settings\dell\my documents\visual studio 2010\projects\genome\genome\genome.cpp(34): error C2784: 'std::basic_ostream<char,_Traits> &std::operator <<(std::basic_ostream<char,_Traits> &,const signed char *)' : could not deduce template argument for 'std::basic_ostream<char,_Traits> &' from 'std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax>'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>,
1>              _Ax=std::allocator<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\ostream(937) : see declaration of 'std::operator <<'
1>c:\documents and settings\dell\my documents\visual studio 2010\projects\genome\genome\genome.cpp(34): error C2784: 'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::operator <<(std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &,_Elem)' : could not deduce template argument for 'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &' from 'std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax>'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>,
1>              _Ax=std::allocator<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\ostream(898) : see declaration of 'std::operator <<'
1>c:\documents and settings\dell\my documents\visual studio 2010\projects\genome\genome\genome.cpp(34): error C2784: 'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::operator <<(std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &,_Elem)' : could not deduce template argument for 'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &' from 'std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax>'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>,
1>              _Ax=std::allocator<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\ostream(898) : see declaration of 'std::operator <<'
1>c:\documents and settings\dell\my documents\visual studio 2010\projects\genome\genome\genome.cpp(34): error C2784: 'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::operator <<(std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &,_Elem)' : could not deduce template argument for 'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &' from 'std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax>'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>,
1>              _Ax=std::allocator<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\ostream(898) : see declaration of 'std::operator <<'
1>c:\documents and settings\dell\my documents\visual studio 2010\projects\genome\genome\genome.cpp(34): error C2784: 'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::operator <<(std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &,const _Elem *)' : could not deduce template argument for 'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &' from 'std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax>'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>,
1>              _Ax=std::allocator<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\ostream(851) : see declaration of 'std::operator <<'
1>c:\documents and settings\dell\my documents\visual studio 2010\projects\genome\genome\genome.cpp(34): error C2784: 'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::operator <<(std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &,const _Elem *)' : could not deduce template argument for 'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &' from 'std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax>'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>,
1>              _Ax=std::allocator<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\ostream(851) : see declaration of 'std::operator <<'
1>c:\documents and settings\dell\my documents\visual studio 2010\projects\genome\genome\genome.cpp(34): error C2784: 'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::operator <<(std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &,const _Elem *)' : could not deduce template argument for 'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &' from 'std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax>'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>,
1>              _Ax=std::allocator<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\ostream(851) : see declaration of 'std::operator <<'
1>c:\documents and settings\dell\my documents\visual studio 2010\projects\genome\genome\genome.cpp(34): error C2784: 'std::basic_ostream<char,_Traits> &std::operator <<(std::basic_ostream<char,_Traits> &,char)' : could not deduce template argument for 'std::basic_ostream<char,_Traits> &' from 'std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax>'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>,
1>              _Ax=std::allocator<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\ostream(811) : see declaration of 'std::operator <<'
1>c:\documents and settings\dell\my documents\visual studio 2010\projects\genome\genome\genome.cpp(34): error C2784: 'std::basic_ostream<char,_Traits> &std::operator <<(std::basic_ostream<char,_Traits> &,char)' : could not deduce template argument for 'std::basic_ostream<char,_Traits> &' from 'std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax>'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>,
1>              _Ax=std::allocator<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\ostream(811) : see declaration of 'std::operator <<'
1>c:\documents and settings\dell\my documents\visual studio 2010\projects\genome\genome\genome.cpp(34): error C2784: 'std::basic_ostream<char,_Traits> &std::operator <<(std::basic_ostream<char,_Traits> &,char)' : could not deduce template argument for 'std::basic_ostream<char,_Traits> &' from 'std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax>'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>,
1>              _Ax=std::allocator<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\ostream(811) : see declaration of 'std::operator <<'
1>c:\documents and settings\dell\my documents\visual studio 2010\projects\genome\genome\genome.cpp(34): error C2784: 'std::basic_ostream<char,_Traits> &std::operator <<(std::basic_ostream<char,_Traits> &,const char *)' : could not deduce template argument for 'std::basic_ostream<char,_Traits> &' from 'std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax>'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>,
1>              _Ax=std::allocator<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\ostream(764) : see declaration of 'std::operator <<'
1>c:\documents and settings\dell\my documents\visual studio 2010\projects\genome\genome\genome.cpp(34): error C2784: 'std::basic_ostream<char,_Traits> &std::operator <<(std::basic_ostream<char,_Traits> &,const char *)' : could not deduce template argument for 'std::basic_ostream<char,_Traits> &' from 'std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax>'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>,
1>              _Ax=std::allocator<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\ostream(764) : see declaration of 'std::operator <<'
1>c:\documents and settings\dell\my documents\visual studio 2010\projects\genome\genome\genome.cpp(34): error C2784: 'std::basic_ostream<char,_Traits> &std::operator <<(std::basic_ostream<char,_Traits> &,const char *)' : could not deduce template argument for 'std::basic_ostream<char,_Traits> &' from 'std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax>'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>,
1>              _Ax=std::allocator<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\ostream(764) : see declaration of 'std::operator <<'
1>c:\documents and settings\dell\my documents\visual studio 2010\projects\genome\genome\genome.cpp(34): error C2784: 'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::operator <<(std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &,char)' : could not deduce template argument for 'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &' from 'std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax>'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>,
1>              _Ax=std::allocator<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\ostream(726) : see declaration of 'std::operator <<'
1>c:\documents and settings\dell\my documents\visual studio 2010\projects\genome\genome\genome.cpp(34): error C2784: 'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::operator <<(std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &,char)' : could not deduce template argument for 'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &' from 'std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax>'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>,
1>              _Ax=std::allocator<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\ostream(726) : see declaration of 'std::operator <<'
1>c:\documents and settings\dell\my documents\visual studio 2010\projects\genome\genome\genome.cpp(34): error C2784: 'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::operator <<(std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &,char)' : could not deduce template argument for 'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &' from 'std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax>'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>,
1>              _Ax=std::allocator<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\ostream(726) : see declaration of 'std::operator <<'
1>c:\documents and settings\dell\my documents\visual studio 2010\projects\genome\genome\genome.cpp(34): error C2784: 'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::operator <<(std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &,const char *)' : could not deduce template argument for 'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &' from 'std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax>'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>,
1>              _Ax=std::allocator<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\ostream(679) : see declaration of 'std::operator <<'
1>c:\documents and settings\dell\my documents\visual studio 2010\projects\genome\genome\genome.cpp(34): error C2784: 'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::operator <<(std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &,const char *)' : could not deduce template argument for 'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &' from 'std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax>'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>,
1>              _Ax=std::allocator<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\ostream(679) : see declaration of 'std::operator <<'
1>c:\documents and settings\dell\my documents\visual studio 2010\projects\genome\genome\genome.cpp(34): error C2784: 'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::operator <<(std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &,const char *)' : could not deduce template argument for 'std::basic_ostream<_Elem,_Traits> &' from 'std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax>'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>,
1>              _Ax=std::allocator<char>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\ostream(679) : see declaration of 'std::operator <<'
1>c:\documents and settings\dell\my documents\visual studio 2010\projects\genome\genome\genome.cpp(34): error C2676: binary '<<' : 'std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax>' does not define this operator or a conversion to a type acceptable to the predefined operator
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Elem=char,
1>              _Traits=std::char_traits<char>,
1>              _Ax=std::allocator<char>
1>          ]
1>c:\documents and settings\dell\my documents\visual studio 2010    1>
1>Time Elapsed 00:00:01.14
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: `if((currentGene.length() % 3) == 0)` should not have a trailing semicolon (unless you really want the following block to be executed every time).

Comment: johnsy do you know what I can do? about my post below

Comment: I'm not sure what's not working as you expect. Applying @john's changes and adding [some debug statements like this](http://ideone.com/aS57gB) may help shed some light...

Comment: Can you reduce this to the *minimal* amount of code needed to reproduce the problem rather than just dumping an entire program?

Answer (score 3):

Add `string::` before `npos`

```
if(genome.find("ATG",0) == string::npos)
                           ^^^^^^^^
```

Delete `<< endl` from this line of code

```
string currentGene = genome.substr(startGene + 3, endGene - (startGene +3)) <<endl;
                                                              DELETE THIS   ^^^^^^
```

Delete `;` from the end of the if statement

```
if((currentGene.length() % 3) == 0);
                      DELETE THIS  ^
```

It's just details but as I'm sure you realise details matter when programming.

Comment: thank you that got ride of most of the error messages but now I'm getting

Comment: Its running now but its not out puting all the genes it displays the first gene TTT but then on the next line it displays GGATGGGGCGTTAGTTGGGCGT and on the next line it displays TT  if it was working correctly it should display TTT then on the next line it should display GGGCGT  Can anyone tell me how to fix this?

Comment: @user2944051 I ran the code and for me it worked the way you said it should. You probably have some mistake in the way you print the genes. Just details again, but you have to get them right. If you can't work it out post again.

Comment: Thanks john your right now Its working correctly I'm Ecstatic